# Update to 2.2 and update commands don't work

Tags: c#, subsonic

I updated my ASP.NET/C# project to version 2.2 of Subsonic, before it was 2.0.3. 
After this update all Update commands don't work! There is no exception, nothing, but the database is not updated!

Someone know how to resolve that? I need to modify something in project or to resolve I have to modify all update commands?

Example, this work before update version of Subsonic:

```
TblCliente.Update(codCliente, txtNomeCliente, Int32.Parse(txtPrograma.Text), txtLinha.Text, txtPrefixo.Text );
```

Comment: can you give a code example of an update command that isn't working?

Comment: Edited! I add a example.

Answer (score 0):

try marking it tblCliente.MarkOld, .MarkClean before setting the values.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make this way. I´m using the 2.2 version and for now I have no problem.

```
TblCliente obj = new TblCliente();

obj.field = xx;
obj.field = yyy;

obj.Save();
```